# Shopify ruby on rails app failying to auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app

I just created a RoR shopify app, with the following generator:

```
rails generate shopify_app --api_key <your_api_key> --secret <your_app_secret>
```

I added my domain to the whitelisted urls and everything but I keep getting this error, it seems like there is something broken inside the shopify app.

The error appears when I put the site's url in my app in order to install it on it (application.delgic.com)

```
F, [2018-05-01T22:01:18.149098 #22506] FATAL -- : [cd2e0b4c-5dfd-422b-959f-7e191bc47ff1]   
F, [2018-05-01T22:01:18.149175 #22506] FATAL -- : [cd2e0b4c-5dfd-422b-959f-7e191bc47ff1] 


ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "shops" does not exist
    LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"shops"'::regclass
                                              ^
    :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                         pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                 (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_collation c, pg_type t
                   WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation),
                         col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                    FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                      ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                   WHERE a.attrelid = '"shops"'::regclass
                     AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                   ORDER BY a.attnum
    ):

F, [2018-05-01T22:01:18.149262 #22506] FATAL -- : [cd2e0b4c-5dfd-422b-959f-7e191bc47ff1]   
F, [2018-05-01T22:01:18.149329 #22506] FATAL -- : [cd2e0b4c-5
```

Also I already ran all the migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Your database table does not exist. So you think you ran migrations successfully, and maybe you did, but your RoR app does not seem to think so. I would open up a console, and see if you can even see the table. If it there, whoa! Something else is going on, and you'll have to provide more info.

Comment: I ran my console and tried something like Shop.last and the table does exist, what other info do you think would help ?

Comment: Are you sure you ran migrations on your production version of the App. You seem to perhaps be caught between a local version and a production version?